# Algebraic numbers in all $\mathbb Q_p$

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-numbers, p-adic

Do there exist non-rational algebraic numbers that belong to $\mathbb Q_p$ for all prime $p$? If yes, can one characterize them?
I spent several days for the first question, and I found nothing. The second one looks even more diffuclt and surely out of my skills.

Comment: See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/7100/30186)

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/16724/622).

Comment: For some $n$ and some $p$, there may be a solution of $X^3=n$ in $\mathbb Q_p$.  But there is no way to say whether a solution on $\mathbb Q_p$ and a solution in $\mathbb Q_q$ are **the same** or not.  So you need to explain how you identify non-rationals in one $\mathbb Q_p$ with those in another.

Comment: One meaningful question of the same spirit: is there an irreducible polynomial of degree $\ge 2$ in $\mathbf{Q}[t]$ that has a root in $\mathbf{Q}_p$ for every $p$? there's none of degree $2$.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar, maybe you are getting at that explicit phrasing, but I think it is completely reasonable to read the question as:  do there exist polynomials with rational coefficients that do not have solutions in $\mathbb Q$, but that have solutions in all $\mathbb Q_p$?  (@‍YCor was giving a better formulation at the same time as I wrote this.)

Comment: @YCor The question I link answers it in negative.

Comment: @Wojowu thanks. So, equivalently, the only algebraic extension of $\mathbf{Q}$ that embeds in $\mathbf{Q}_p$ for all primes $p$ [or even for a density 1 set of primes] is $\mathbf{Q}$ itself.

Comment: Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now.

Comment: Please let us know if the answer Wojowu linked to doesn't answer your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(cw answer based on Wojowu's link)

> The only algebraic extension of $\mathbf{Q}$ that embeds into $\mathbf{Q}_p$ for all $p$ (or even for a density 1 set of primes) is $\mathbf{Q}$ itself.

For if $P\in\mathbf{Q}[t]$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree $\ge 2$, the set of primes $p$ for which $P$ has no root in $\mathbf{Q}_p$ has positive density: see [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/7100/30186), which also applies to an arbitrary number field (=finite extension of $\mathbf{Q}$), where primes now mean primes of the number field.

The above statement roughly states that *"the only algebraic number that belong to the intersection of all $\mathbf{Q}_p$ are rationals"*, which seems to answer your question. As already mentioned in comments, this statement doesn't really make sense, since there is no natural way to identify algebraic elements in different completions. An artificial way for it to makes sense is to mod out $\mathbf{Q}_p$ by the equivalence relation "having the same minimal polynomial (monic or zero) over $\mathbf{Q}$".